# Disk Space Merging

Tags: windows-8, disk-space

I am using Windows 8. How can I merge two unallocated disk space ?

[image]

Comment: You can boot using a Linux [GParted LiveUSB](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php) to move the D: partition. You probably want to back up your data first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Instead, you must move the D: partition. Because it appears to be empty, it’ll be quicker to just delete it and re-create it at either end of the resulting free space.

It would be possible to do this with Dynamic Disks. But as far as I know, you cannot convert from GPT to Dynamic Disk.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel B for your reply. I have content in D: partition, so it is not possible for me to delete it.

Comment: I’m sure you can temporarily move it elsewhere. Disk Management shows it as 100% free, so it can’t be that much.